Multiple web apps in azure gives socket exception
I'm new to Azure portal and DevOps in general.
Some context:
I recently created a new App Service(Web app) in azure which will be my production environment.
I used the same app plan as my UAT environment(in case this matters).
I followed the process for registering a custom domain etc.
This web app is successfully connected with my DevOps Repository as well.
Issue statement:
The problem that I have at the moment is that when I run both the Production web app and the UAT web app simultaneously, I get an exception that reads:
Application: w3wp.exe
CoreCLR Version: 8.0.524.21615
.NET Version: 8.0.5
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10013): An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.UpdateStatusAfterSocketErrorAndThrowException(SocketError error, Boolean disconnectOnFailure, String callerName)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoBind(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Bind(EndPoint localEP)
   at Orleans.Networking.Shared.SocketConnectionListener.Bind() in /_/src/Orleans.Core/Networking/Shared/SocketConnectionListener.cs:line 71
   at Orleans.Networking.Shared.SocketConnectionListenerFactory.BindAsync(EndPoint endpoint, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/Orleans.Core/Networking/Shared/SocketConnectionListenerFactory.cs:line 41
   at Orleans.Runtime.Messaging.ConnectionListener.BindAsync() in /_/src/Orleans.Runtime/Networking/ConnectionListener.cs:line 78
   at Orleans.Runtime.SiloLifecycleSubject.MonitoredObserver.OnStart(CancellationToken ct) in /_/src/Orleans.Runtime/Lifecycle/SiloLifecycleSubject.cs:line 134
   at Orleans.LifecycleSubject.OnStart(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/Orleans.Core/Lifecycle/LifecycleSubject.cs:line 118
   at Orleans.Runtime.Scheduler.AsyncClosureWorkItem.Execute() in /_/src/Orleans.Runtime/Scheduler/ClosureWorkItem.cs:line 33
   at Orleans.Runtime.Silo.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/Orleans.Runtime/Silo/Silo.cs:line 201
   at Orleans.Hosting.SiloHostedService.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/Orleans.Runtime/Hosting/SiloHostedService.cs:line 28
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.<StartAsync>b__15_1(IHostedService service, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.ForeachService[T](IEnumerable1 services, CancellationToken token, Boolean concurrent, Boolean abortOnFirstException, List1 exceptions, Func3 operation)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.<StartAsync>g__LogAndRethrow|15_3(<>c__DisplayClass15_0&)
...

The short-term solution I'm using is keeping the production web app deactivated, as users are still using the UAT environment anyway.
How do I get a permanent solution for the above exception that allows me to run both web apps?
TIA

According to the error message, the app is trying to listen on the port without enough permissions to fo that.

I found the solution. I had to put the web apps into VMs and create private ports for them then connect Orleans to those ports
